# lookup and sumifs an item for specific date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a data bank in excel that i want to get sum of an item in specific date in another workbook file, i try to find a solution with excel function instead of macro. i made a file to explain what i mean:

[image]

picture above is like my data bank,i want in another file if i enter a date, for example all A items with good quality to be summed, for 7/10/2016 answer is 8.
i don't know how to use hlookup and sumifs for it (for now i think hlookup and sumifs could answer my question). please help me to solve this problem

Comment: This would be a lot easier it you did not have the merged cells but the value in every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in H2 is the date, H4 the item and H6 the quality then use something like:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A102,H4,INDEX(C:E,MATCH(H6,B2:B4)+1,MATCH(H2,C1:E1)):INDEX(C:E,MATCH(H6,B2:B4)+101,MATCH(H2,C1:E1)))
```

[image]

It would be less complex with `OFFSET`, but I tried to avoid volatile functions ;)

Comment: Making sure I understand your formula.  This depends on there always being three qualities and in the same order?

Comment: Ya... It is exclusively for the offered layout. As already said: the merged cells are the troublemaker :/

Answer (score 0):

If you unmerge the items column, you can use a simple [PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to view all sums (or any filter of them) at once:
[image]